# Where to get Tobin's Q by country

Tags: equities, statistics

I am trying to rank countries based on Tobin's Q ratio. US data can be easily gathered from FED's report and is available on multiple website.

I want get data on other countries with high Index of Economic Freedom.

Can anyone suggest sources that might have this data?

Comment: I know that estimates are availed on Thompson Reuters Datastream, however, that's not for free but most universities provide access.

Answer (score 1):

Data to compute Tobin's Q for most other countries, particularly emerging countries, are not available. As a result, many economists have begun to use the ratio of the stock market capitalization to GDP as an approximation for Tobin's Q.